# When did "and" become an operator in C++

Tags: c++, g++

I have some code that looks like:

```
static const std::string and(" AND ");
```

This causes an error in g++ like so:

```
Row.cpp:140: error: expected unqualified-id before '&&' token
```

so after cursing the fool that defined "and" as &&, I added

```
#ifdef and
#undef and
#endif
```

and now I get

```
Row.cpp:9:8: error: "and" cannot be used as a macro name as it is an operator in C++
```

Which leads to my question of WHEN did "and" become an operator in C++?  I can't find anything that indicates it is, except of course this message from g++

Comment: It was first introduced into C94, i think. See http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/na1.html . While being macros in C, they are preprocessor operators in C++ so you can not `#define` them. (They are not keywords, technically. But also not all keywords are reserved in such a way. One which is, is `new`. One which is not, for example, is `sizeof`. So you may `#define sizeof`).

Comment: For that, notice this issue report: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#369 . Currently a `#define` of `delete` or `new` is not allowed.

Comment: Just as an FYI for MSVC users, if you want them to work in MSVC you need to enable the `/Za` option to put the compiler in strict ANSI mode or you need to include `iso646.h` (or `ciso646`).

Comment: Of course, why you're creating a `std::string` where a `const char*` would work just fine and optimize better is another question... as is why you would want to define an alias for `" AND "`... It's not like the next version of SQL is threatening to change it to `" AHND "` and break things...

Comment: Turns out that in C, these are only keywords if you include iso646 but in C++ they are always keywords.  g++ just happens to be a little more up to date in regards to the spec.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are [several such alternatives](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) defined in C++.  You can probably use switches to turn these on/off.

Answer (score 32):

From the C++03 standard, section 2.5:

2.5 Alternative tokens

Alternative token representations are provided for some operators and punctuators. In all respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token, except for its spelling. The set of alternative tokens is defined in Table 2.

Table 2—alternative tokens

```
alternative primary 
  <%         { 
  %>         } 
  <:         [ 
  :>         ] 
  %:         # 
  %:%:       ## 
  and        && 
  bitor      | 
  or         || 
  xor        ˆ 
  compl      ˜ 
  bitand     & 
  and_eq     &= 
  or_eq      |= 
  xor_eq     ˆ= 
  not        ! 
  not_eq     !=
```

Comment: ... Trigraphs: The Next Generation? ... And they define `not_eq` but not `eq`?  The unfairness!

Answer (score 15):

They've been there since C++ 98. They're listed in the §2.5/2 of the standard (either the 1998 or the 2003 edition). The alternate tokens include: `and`, `or`, `xor`, `not`, `bitand`, `bitor`, `compl`, `and_eq`, `or_eq`, `xor_eq`, `not`, `not_eq`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `-fno-operator-names` to disable this. Alternatively, you can name your `std::string` object something else!

Answer (score 6):

According to C++ Standard 2.12 there are predefined preprocessor tokens "which are used in
the syntax of the preprocessor or are converted into tokens for operators and punctuators." `and` is one of them. In new C++ Standard there is new 2.12/2:

> Furthermore, the alternative representations shown in Table 4 for certain operators and punctuators (2.6) **are reserved and shall not be used** otherwise:
>
> ```
> and and_eq bitand bitor compl not
> not_eq or or_eq xor xor_eq
> ```

Answer (score 4):

They were added because some of those characters are difficult to type on some keyboards.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know when it was introduced, it may well have been there from the beginning, but I believe the reason it's there is as an alternative to `&&` for people with restricted character sets i.e. where they don't actually have the ampersand character.

There are many others too eg. `and_eq`, `or`, `compl` and `not` to name just a selection.

Comment: What do those people do when they need a bitwise and (&)?

Comment: @tloach `bitand`