# At what stage of compilation are reserved identifiers reserved?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, reserved-words

Just a little curiosity at work, here. While working on something dangerous, I got to thinking about the implementations of various compilers and their associated standard libraries. Here's the progression of my thoughts:

1. Some classes of identifiers are reserved for implementation use in C++ and C.
2. A compiler must perform the stages of compilation (preprocessing, compilation, linking) as though they were performed in sequence.
3. The C preprocessor is not aware of the reserved status of identifiers.
4. Therefore, a program may use reserved identifiers *if and only if*:

   1. The reserved identifiers used are all preprocessor symbols.
   2. The preprocessing result does not include reserved identifiers.
   3. The identifiers do not conflict with symbols predefined by the compiler (`GNUC` et. al.)

Is this valid? I'm uncertain on points 3 and 4.3. Moreover, is there a way to test it?

Comment: Each name defined as a macro in a header of the Standard Library is a reserved name. So the preprocessor should know about reserved names.

Comment: Do you refer to reserved preprocessor identifiers (for example, the MSVC `#pragma warning`) or the reserved language identifiers (example, digraphs, identifiers with `__`)?

Comment: @Kirill: I mean that the standard does not come close to requiring that the preprocessor warn about use of such identifiers, or that any stage of compilation do so.

Comment: Related but not identical question, pertaining to C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726204/c-preprocessor-define-ing-a-keyword-is-it-standards-conforming

Comment: @John: Reserved language identifiers (`^_[A-Z]`, `__`, and POSIX `_t$` and `^E_`).

Comment: I'm not a compiler writer, so can only speculate.  But I speculate that the preprocessor knows nothing about the language itself.  It only knows about its own language, and is just a fairly dumb macro processor.

Comment: @John:  Correct, the preprocessor is a textual replacement engine and doesn't "know" about C or C++.  It could be used in many other languages, except that nobody would want to do that.  There are better general-purpose preprocessors.

Comment: @John:  The preprocessor does have to "understand" parts of the languages.  For one thing, the preprocessor operates on preprocessing tokens, not on raw text.  Preprocessing tokens form a fundamental part of the language grammars.  A C++ preprocessor must also be able to recognize the `true` and `false` keywords (whereas in a C preprocessor, those are not keywords, they are macros defined in `<stdbool.h>`).  There are other things; those are just two that come to mind.  (I too thought the preprocessor was dumber than it is, until I implemented most of the C and C++ preprocessors this year).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(The comments on the question explain that we're talking about **reserved identifiers** in the sense of C99 section 7.1.3, i.e., identifiers matching `/^_[A-Z_]/` anywhere, `/^_/` in file scope, `/^str[a-z]/` with external linkage, etc.  So here's my guess at at least a part of what you're asking...)

They're not reserved in the sense that (any particular phase of) the compiler is expected to diagnose their misuse.  Rather, they're reserved in that if you're foolish enough to (mis)use them yourself, you don't get to complain if your program stops working or stops compiling at a later date.

We've all seen what happens when people with only a dangerous amount of knowledge look inside system headers and then write their own header guards:

```
#ifndef _MYHEADER_H
#define _MYHEADER_H
// ...
#endif
```

They're invoking undefined behaviour, but nothing diagnoses this as "*error: reserved identifier used by end-user code*".  Instead mostly they're lucky and all is well; but occasionally they collide with an identifier of interest to the implementation, and confusing things happen.

Similarly, I often have an externally-visible function named `strip()` or so:

```
char *strip(char *s) {
  // remove leading whitespace
  }
```

By my reading of C99's 7.1.3, 7.26, and 7.26.11, this invokes undefined behaviour.  However I have decided not to care about this.  The identifier is not reserved in that anything bad is expected to happen today, but because the Standard reserves to itself the right to invent a new standard `str-ip()` routine in a future revision.  And I've decided that I reckon *string*-`ip`, whatever that might be, is an unlikely name for a string operation to be added in the future -- so in the unlikely event that happens, I'll cross that bridge when I get to it.  Technically I'm invoking undefined behaviour, but I don't expect to get bitten.

Finally, a counter-example to your point 4:

```
#include <string.h>
#define memcpy(d,s,n)  (my_crazy_function((n), (s)))
void foo(char *a, char *b) {
  memcpy(a, b, 5);  // intends to invoke my_crazy_function
  memmove(a, b, 5); // standard behaviour expected
}
```

This complies with your 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 (if I understand your intention on that last one).  However, if `memmove` is additionally implemented as a macro (via 7.1.4/1) that is written in terms of `memcpy`, then you're going to be in trouble.

Comment: The other practical upshot of `strip` being a reserved identifier is that an implementation *today* is free to implement such a function, and be conforming.  So eg. `strdup()` can be defined even in strictly conforming mode.

Comment: Do you have any idea why C99 added the restrict keyword instead of calling it _\_restrict, _\_restrict_\_, or _Restrict, and so using one of the reserved identifiers? C99 also adds _Bool, rather than bool, so that does use a reserved identifier.

Answer (score 2):

The story is more complicated than that, I think, at least for the *if and only if*. What I recall from C99:

E.g 3. is false, the `defined` token is reserved even in the preprocessing phase, and pseudo-macros like `__LINE__`, `__func__` etc may not be redefined either.

Then, the reservation of identifiers depends on the scope.

- Some identifiers are explicitly
  reserved for external symbols, e.g
  `setjmp`.
- Identifiers with starting with
  underscore and then another
  underscore or a capital letter are
  reserved everywhere in C. You should
  never touch them, even with the
  preprocessor.
- Identifiers starting with underscore
  and then a lowercase letter are
  forbidden in file scope since they
  may refer to external symbols. They
  can be used freely in function scope.

4.2 is not completely correct either. First it is only *undefined behavior* (aka very evil) to have a macro defined that has a keyword as its name under the following condition:

> A standard header is included while a
>   macro is defined with the same name as
>   a keyword (7.1.2).

Then, a macro that contains its own name in its expansion is "safe", since the expansion is guaranteed not to be recursive. Something like the following would be valid, though not recommended:

```
#define if(...)                                         \
for(int _i = 0; _i < 1; ++_i)                           \
  for(int _cond = (__VA_ARGS__);                        \
      _i < 1;                                           \
      printf("line %d val %d\n", __LINE__, _cond),      \
        ++_i)                                           \
    if(_cond)
```

(BTW, don't anyone use that macro, it compiles and does about what it looks like, but has corner cases that let it explode.)

Comment: In C++ the restriction is more stringent:  you cannot define a macro with a name lexically identical to a keyword in any translation unit that includes a standard library header, even if the macro is not defined when the header is included.

Answer (score 2):

> The C preprocessor is not aware of the reserved status of identifiers.

I'm not sure what you mean by "aware", but I don't think you can necessarily assume this - 7.1.3 says

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore an either an uppercase or another underscore are always reserved for any use

The preprocessor (or compiler) implementation can use these reserved identifiers for whatever purposes suit it - it doesn't need to warn you if you're misusing these identifiers.

I'd suggest that "a program may use reserved identifiers if and only if" the standard (for example the set of pre-defined macros) or the implementation says so in its documentation.

Of course, I think you'll get away with using identifiers that are reserved in quite a few cases - implementations don't go out of their way to cause you problems. An awful lot of code uses names that are reserved, and I'd guess that implementations would rather not break that code without good enough reason.  However, it would be best if you avoided that namespace altogether if you're not implementing a compiler toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers like `_UNDERSCORE_CAP` and `double__underscore` are reserved for use by the implementation as it sees fit.  It's not a problem if the implementation uses them, such as having, say, a `_File` identifier or macro in `<stdio.h>`, that's what the reservation is for.  It is a potential problem if the user uses one.

Therefore, in order to diagnose this, the compiler would have to keep track of where identifiers came from.  It wouldn't be sufficient to just check code not in `<angle_bracket_files.h>`, since those can define macros that might be used and are likely to expand to something using implementation-reserved words.  For example, `isupper` might be defined in `<ctype.h>` as

```
#define isupper(x) (_UPPER_BIT & _CHAR_TRAITS[x])
```

or some such.  (It's been a long time since I saw the definition I based the above on.)

Therefore, to keep track of this, the preprocessor would have to maintain records on which macro came from there, among other things.  Tracking that would complicate the preprocessor considerably, to what compiler writers appear to think no corresponding gain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can `#define if while` and make your code unreadable, then yes. This was a common practice in the obfuscated C competition.  This would actually go against your 4.2, though.

For things like GNUC, these are predefined, but you can usually redefine them and undef them.  It is not really a good idea to do this, but you can.  More interesting would be redefining or undefining `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, and preprocessor symbols like that (b/c they change automatically).

Comment: I'm not asking that, actually, though I got it from a linked question anyway.