# Absence of typeof operator in C++03?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, metaprogramming, typeof

I'm just wondering how boost have implemented [BOOST_TYPEOF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/typeof.html) (in C++03) which seems to be a very useful tool. Anyone has any idea?

Also, I'm thinking C++03 itself could have provided `typeof` operator, especially when it already has `sizeof(expr)` which **must** be knowing the *type* of the `expr` also, otherwise how else could it tell us the *size*, without knowing the *type*?Is it really possible to know the *size*, without knowing the *type* of an expression?

If it doesn't know the *type*, then compiler tells us the *size* of what (if not *type*)? I mean, `sizeof(unknowntype)` wouldn't make sense to the compilers (and humans as well)!

Comment: C++03 *could* have provided a lot of things. But the standard was already *huge* as it was, and they weren't keen on adding more than was absolutely necessary. So they left out a lot of things that, by their own admission, would be nice to have. Of course, C++0x gives you `decltype` which solves the problem.

Comment: @jalf : What I meant by *"C++03 could have provided..."* is that compilers already implement `sizeof()`, and that is not possible unless it clearly discovers the *type* of the expression. That means, in order to provide `typeof()` operator, compilers do not need to do extra things. In fact, `typeof()` comes free with `sizeof()`, as I think the latter requires more inspection/analysis/work than the former.

Comment: There's no such thing as "free". At the very least, there's additional testing to be done. But you're also underestimating the complexity. Getting the type of an expression is simple enough *in the simple case*, but you need to make a lot of decisions about whether to preserve CV-qualifiers and references, for example. `decltype` has a few odd rules to cope with this. But second, *getting* the type is the easy part. Then you need to figure out how it should interact with other parts of the language. Should you be allowed to do this: `std::vector<typeof(4)>`? That doesn't come "for free"

Comment: But my point still stands. Yes, it *could* have been implemented and it *would* have been useful, but it would have made the language bigger and more complex, and it already took nearly a decade for compilers to catch up with the standard as it is. They had to draw the line somewhere. They also butchered the STL, leaving out something like two thirds of it, simply because they couldn't afford to make the language too much bigger.

Comment: Just to illustrate, `sizeof` throws away references. If you invoke `sizeof` on a variable of type `int&`, it gives you the size of an int. But should `typeof` on the same variable return `int` or `int&`?

Comment: @Nawaz: "could have had" is always a very simplifying and attention grabbing phrase that is easy to state afterwards (if intended to be a rant). Maybe it would have had it if you would have been in the committee then? But technically, I agree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It just uses compiler magics. Like, GCC's `__typeof__`. For compilers that don't provide such magic, it provides an emulation that can detect the type of *some* expressions, but fails with completely unknown types.

A possible implementation could be to have a list of functions that accept an expression of a given type, and then dispatch from that type to a number using a class template. To make the function template return the number as a compile time entity, we put it into an array dimension

```
template<typename> struct type2num;
template<int> struct num2type;
template<typename T> typename type2num<T>::dim &dispatch(T const&);
```

Then it goes from that number back to the type, so that our `EMUL_TYPEOF` could directly name the type. So to register a type, we write

```
#define REGISTER_TYPE(T, N) \
  template<> \
  struct type2num<T> { \
    static int const value = N; \
    typedef char dim[N]; \
  }; \
  template<> \
  struct num2type<N> { typedef T type; }
```

Having this in place, you can write

```
#define EMUL_TYPEOF(E) \
  num2type<sizeof dispatch(E)>::type
```

Whenever you need to register a type, you write

```
REGISTER_TYPE(int, 1);
REGISTER_TYPE(unsigned int, 2);
// ...
```

Of course, now you find you need a mechanism to accept `vector<T>`, where you don't know `T` in advance and then it gets arbitrary complex. You could create a system where the numbers mean more than just a type. This could probably work:

```
#define EMUL_TYPEOF(E) \
  build_type<sizeof dispatch_1(E), sizeof dispatch_2(E)>::type
```

This could detect types like `int` and also types like `shared_ptr<int>` - in other words, types that aren't class template specializations, and class template specializations with one template argument, by doing some kind of systematical mapping

- If the first number yields 1, the second number specifies a type; otherwise
- the first number specifies a template, and the second number its first type template argument

So this becomes

```
template<int N, int M>
struct build_type {
  typedef typename num2tmp<N>::template apply<
    typename num2type<M>::type>::type type;
};

template<int N>
struct build_type<1, N> {
  typedef num2type<N>::type type;
};
```

We also need to change the `dispatch` template and split it up in two versions, shown below, alongside the `REGISTER_TEMP1` for registering one-argument templates

```
template<typename T> typename type2num<T>::dim1 &dispatch_1(T const&);
template<typename T> typename type2num<T>::dim2 &dispatch_2(T const&);

#define REGISTER_TYPE(T, N) \
  template<> \
  struct type2num<T> { \
    static int const value_dim1 = 1; \
    static int const value_dim2 = N; \
    typedef char dim1[value_dim1]; \
    typedef char dim2[value_dim2]; \
  }; \
  template<> \
  struct num2type<N> { typedef T type; }

#define REGISTER_TMP1(Te, N) \
  template<typename T1> \
  struct type2num< Te<T1> > { \
    static int const value_dim1 = N; \
    static int const value_dim2 = type2num<T1>::value_dim2; \
    typedef char dim1[value_dim1]; \
    typedef char dim2[value_dim2]; \
  }; \
  template<> struct num2tmp<N> { \
    template<typename T1> struct apply { \
      typedef Te<T1> type; \
    }; \
  }
```

Registering the `std::vector` template and both `int` variants now look like

```
REGISTER_TMP1(std::vector, 2);
// ... REGISTER_TMP1(std::list, 3);

REGISTER_TYPE(int, 1);
REGISTER_TYPE(unsigned int, 2);
// ... REGISTER_TYPE(char, 3);
```

You probably also want to register multiple numbers with each type, one number for each combination of const/volatile or may need more than one number per type for recording `*`, `&` and such. You also want to support `vector< vector<int> >`, so you need more than one number for the template argument too, making `build_type` call itself recursively. As you can create an arbitrary long list of integers, you can encode anything into that sequence anyway, so it's just up to your creativity on how to represent these things.

In the end, you are probably reimplementing BOOST_TYPEOF :)

Comment: You presented a great impetus for further thought. thanks :-)

Answer (score 6):

From memory, boost::typeof is implemented via some ?: hacks. First, you start with a class that can be converted to any other class, like

```
class something {
public:
    template<typename T> operator const T&() {
        return *(T*)0;
    }
};
```

The ?: rules state that if both sides have the same type, then the result is that type. Else, if one type can be converted to the other type, that is the result type. So by doing

```
true ? something() : expr;
```

the result type is (a const reference to) the type of expr- but expr is never actually evaluated, because it's on the false branch. So then you pass it to some place that already has argument deduction, such as function arguments.

```
template<typename T> void x(const T& t) {
    // T is the type of expr.
}
```

This is somewhat more complex because from memory, C++03 doesn't have reference collapsing, so it is likely somewhat more convoluted than this example- most likely using SFINAE and type traits.

How this is converted into an actual compile-time type that you can pass into a template, I have no idea. As for C++03 providing decltype(), well, there are far bigger problems with the C++03 language, like ODR and declaration/definition orders, no move semantics, etc, which are much worse than not providing decltype.

Comment: BTW- can you elaborate on how ODR is a problem with C++? I've always found it a natural rule, but I may be missing something.

Comment: @DeadMG : your last paragraph doesn't make sense to me. The topic is about `typeof`. So when compiler already knows the  *size* of *type* of an expression, then it's obvious that it knows the *type* as well.

Comment: @Kos: Because you spend your life telling the compiler things it already knows but happen to be in other translation units, or have to be declared and then defined, or any old bullshit like that, which is a colossal waste of programmer time. @Nawaz: What I'm saying is that C++, 03 or 0x, already has so many wtfs, that not providing decltype in 03 is pretty low on the list of "What was the committee smoking?".

Comment: @DeadMG, I believe you're mentioning the necessity of redeclaring anything in many translation units (which I indeed hate); how's that related to One Definition Rule? Are we talking about the same ODR? :)

Comment: @Kos: That's not it. ODR says that you can't define a non-inline function in a header, so if you have a class with a hundred member functions, you have to define them all again in some translation unit, forcing you to repeat every argument, every return type, and maintain said when it changes. Declarations are another WTF all on their own.

Comment: @DeadMG, in that case I'd say that both of the problems we mention fall under one name: "C/C++ have translation units instead of modules".

Comment: @Kos: Indeed. It's way past the translation unit sell-by date.

Answer (score 0):

It's defined as:

```
#define BOOST_TYPEOF(Expr) \
boost::type_of::decode_begin<BOOST_TYPEOF_ENCODED_VECTOR(Expr) >::type
```

I don't know the details, but it seems to look up the type in some sort of table, and expands to (the table entry)::type

No, it's not possible to know the size without knowing the type. It's just that nobody thought to add typeof to C++03.

Answer (score 0):

Since boost is distributed as source code (and BOOST_TYPEOF available is a header file implementation in any case), you could of course just take a look.  It has lots of compiler specific conditional compilation, so the answer is that it is compiler specific.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly the same as `typeof`, C++0x has `decltype`.

Comment: How is decltype not the same as typeof?

Comment: I know that C++0x has decltype but that is not the question here. you should write such thing in comments.