# How do I typecast with type_info?

Tags: c++, casting, rtti

I've stored a pointer to a `type_info` object.

```
int MyVariable = 123;
const std::type_info* Datatype = &typeid(MyVariable);
```

How might I use this to typecast another variable to that type?  I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
std::cout << ((*Datatype)3.14) << std::endl;
```

Using the function form of typecasting doesn't work, either:

```
std::cout << (*Datatype(3.14)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: I don't suppose this could be added as a feature in fůtůrë c++ versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think such casting can be done. Suppose you *could* do "dynamic" casting like this at runtime (not to mean `dynamic_cast`). Then if you used the result of the cast to call a function the compiler could no longer do type checking on the parameters and you could invoke a function call that doesn't actually exist.

Therefore it's not possible for this to work.

Comment: If you use a C-style or reinterpret_cast you get the same problem, so I don't think it's a valid argument.

Comment: @Mark Ransom The result of either of those cast types is *known at compile time*. The contents of `*DataType` may vary at runtime.

Comment: on that point I think we agree and I said as much in my answer. Where I disagree is that the problem of losing type checking would be a reason for this not to work. If you cast a `foo *` to a `bar *` and call a method on it, you can invoke a function call that doesn't actually exist - today, using the casts I mentioned.

Comment: While your conclusion may be correct, your logic of arriving there isn't. Methods are passed the `this` parameter, à la `foo(Foo* this, ...)` so the function would exist, but the `this` pointer could, hypothetically, point to a non-`Foo` object.

Answer (score 19):

Simply you cannot do that using `type_info`. Also, in your example `DataType` is not a *type*, it's a *pointer* to an object of type `type_info`. You cannot use it to cast. Casting requires *type*, not pointer or object!

---

In C++0x, you can do this however,

```
    int MyVariable = 123;

    cout << (decltype(MyVariable))3.14 << endl;

    cout << static_cast<decltype(MyVariable)>(3.14) << endl;
```

Output:

```
3
3
```

Online Demo: http://www.ideone.com/ViM2w

Comment: Blech.  Another reason to wait for C++0x.

Comment: @Maxpm, much of C++0x is available in Boost, so I went searching: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/typeof.html

Comment: @Mark Ransom : I think `Boost.Typeof` is not portable, or simply doesn't work with all compilers, as it uses compiler extension internally. See this topic : [Absence of typeof operator in C++03?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533758/absence-of-typeof-operator-in-c03)

Answer (score 4):

Typecasting isn't a run-time process, it's a compile-time process at least for the type you're casting *to*. I don't think it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use fragile, GCC-specific logic, take a look at the [__dynamic_cast](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/cxxabi.h#L599) and [__do_upcast](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/typeinfo#LL146C18-L146C29) methods. These approximately correspond to dynamic_cast<> and static_cast<> and can be used to cast void * pointers for which you have the std::type_info.