# Can you look up a type using its typeinfo?

Tags: c++, rtti, typeid, typeinfo

Say you have the type info for a class, is it possible to get that type using its `typeinfo`? Basically, if `typeid` maps a `typeinfo` to a type is it possible to do the reverse and map a `type` to a `typeinfo`?

(I doubt there is but since `C++` never ceases to surprise me both pleasantly and unpleasantly I thought I'd ask)

Comment: What do you mean by "get that type"?  What would you do with a type if you could get it?

Comment: Since the only use of types you can possibly make is at compile-time, I suspect that what you are looking for is `decltype`, not `typeid`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: What does this even mean? How would you "get a type" and use it?

Comment: You're probably looking for some variant on "clone", "factory" or "any".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I mean determine the type for use in things like a cast. E.g. myClass* c = static_cast<TypeForName<myTypeInfo.name()>::value*>(aPtrInAPool);

Comment: Maybe you mean [decltype()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)? (C++11 only)

Comment: @Mattia: You seem to be confusing runtime and compile-time information.  Templates are evaluated at *compile-time*.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I probably am confused somewhere but I don't think I am about templates being evaluated at compile time. What about my comment or question makes you think I'm confused about the compile-time/run-time distinction? (Genuinely curious btw)

Comment: @Mattia: Sorry, misread your previous comment.  `static_cast` (etc.) is compile-time, `typeinfo` (and RTTI in general) are run-time.

Comment: [How do I typecast with type_info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972795/how-do-i-typecast-with-type-info) (TL;DR: You can't.)

Comment: @remyabel: thanks for the link! Didn't find it when looking earlier

Comment: Just out of curiosity: I can see closing this question as a duplicate but why down vote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It is not possible.  That is all.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Type in c++ is compile time information only. typeinfo is runtime information. What could you do with type in runtime? Nothing.