# How to pass multiple types into single QTest::addColumn call

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qtestlib, qttest

I have a template function for serializing data to a file and another to retrieve it back using the ID returned by the fist function:

```
template<typename T> int serialize(const T &value); //returns id
template<typename T> T deserialize(int id);
```

Now I want to create a unit test for these with number of types using `QTest` framework, the relevant incomplete `private slots`:

```
void serialization_data()
{
    QTest::addColumn<???>("data");
    QTest::addColumn<int>("id"); //id is assigned sequentially starting from 0

    QTest::newRow("row1") << QByteArray("Array") << 0;
    QTest::newRow("row2") << QString("String") << 1;
    // etc. 
}

void serialization()
{
    QFETCH(???, data);
    QFETCH(int, id);

    QVERIFY(serialize(data) == id);
    QVERIFY(deserialize<???>(id) == data);
}
```

My question basically is what should be the substitue of `???`.

**Spelling it out**

Obvious solution for completeness sake. I am specifically trying to find a solution that would not require typing it all out.

**QVariant**

One workaround is using `QVariant`. The problems with that are many. First it is rather messy, even when using Qt types because things like `QVector<qint64>` require registering them to the meta system, registering their streaming operators AND registering their comparison operators... Furthermore it adds serialization of the `QVariant` itself to the mix and serializing custom types in `QVariant` apparently involves some further data written than the types themselves. It certainly is not just what the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/datastreamformat.html) say it should be for `QVariant` - I guess it might have to do with the meta system and its special streaming methods that are [invoked when serializing custom types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#save) in `QVariant`.

**void* and dynamic_cast?**

Another option I thought of was using `typeid`'s result `type_info` along with `void*`. The `???` would be replaced by `void`* in the `_data` and another column containing the `const type_info*` would be provided so that the test method could convert it to the proper type and dereference it. [But that is unfortunately not possible it seems.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972795/how-do-i-typecast-with-type-info)

Are there any other options?