# A Portable typeof() in C++ using SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, typeof, sfinae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Absence of typeof operator in C++03?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533758/absence-of-typeof-operator-in-c03)

Is it possible to use templates to get the *compile-time* type of an expression *portably* in pre-C++0x C++?

Something like:

```
int foo() { return 0; } //Let's say we have this
typeof(foo()) x;        //x would now be of type 'int'
```

but since we're working with templates, slightly different syntax might be needed obviously.

(I've seen many duplicates here and elsewhere on the web, but they either seem to rely on compiler-specific features or on C++0x (C++11?) `decltype` features.)

Comment: @Kirill: That duplicate uses C++0x... if the answer is "it's impossible" then that's the answer I guess. Feel free to post that if you're confident. :)

Comment: Read this : [Absence of typeof operator in C++03?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533758/absence-of-typeof-operator-in-c03)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible in the general case. And yes, quite a lot of effort has been put into this problem over the years.

There are a lot of tricks for determining the type of an expression *in specific* cases (for example, functors are commonly annotated with a typedef indicating their return type), but *in general*, you need `decltype`, which is precisely why it was added in C++0x. The standards committee follows a policy of not adding core language features to do something a library could have done just as well.

Comment: +1, for `committee follows a policy of not adding core language features to do something a library could have done`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the implementation, but take a look at [Boost.Typeof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/typeof.html).

Comment: Boost requires registration of all the types. Far from automatic.

Comment: @Bo Persson: not all types. For instance, not `int& (*)(const volatile char*, double[5], void(*)(short))`. And certainly not `int`, as is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

It's **NOT possible**. The only compile time operation you can perform with a function/method is `sizeof()`, which doesn't help deducing a type (like `typeid`).