# How to implement std::result_of with only c++98 features?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, metaprogramming, c++98

I wonder how can we implement a result_of template class to get the return type of a function.

I know C++11 has std::result_of or decltype. But how the boost implement this feature in C++98 standard?

I have tried to learn from source code, but I didn't get the point.

It should be like this:

```
int fint() { return 0;}
double fdouble() { return double(0);}
cout << sizeof(result_of<fint>::type) << endl; // should be 4
cout << sizeof(result_of<fdouble>::type) << endl; // should be 8
result_of<fint>::type x; // same as `int x;`
result_of<fdouble>::type y; // same as `double y;`
```

Comment: @tobi303 yes, I have corrected

Comment: specialize for `Ret (*) (T1, ...,TN)` up to some `N`.

Comment: its an interesting question, but you already know the answer: boost implements it. Imho it would be better if you say what you dont understand on the boost code, because I doubt that someone will come up with something much simpler than what boost did

Comment: I can't tell exactly where is wrong, but code is just unable to compile....

Answer (score 4):

Specialize for `Ret (*) (T1, ...,TN)` up to some `N`:

```
template <typename T> struct result_of;

template <typename Ret> struct result_of<Ret (*)()> {
    typedef Ret type;
};

template <typename Ret, typename T1> struct result_of<Ret (*)(T1)> {
    typedef Ret type;
};

template <typename Ret, typename T1>
struct result_of<Ret (*)(T1, ...)> { /* ellipsis as for printf */
    typedef Ret type;
};

template <typename Ret, typename T1, typename T2> struct result_of<Ret (*)(T1, T2)> {
    typedef Ret type;
};

// ...
```

Comment: result_of.cpp:71:15: error: ‘float f_f()’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
     result_of<f_f()>::type a = 3;
               ^
result_of.cpp:71:19: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
     result_of<f_f()>::type a = 3;

Comment: I cann't pass a function call to template parameter. It's not defined at compiling time.

Comment: @LiuWeibo  `f_f()` isnt a function, but `f_f` is

Comment: result_of.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
result_of.cpp:71:18: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class RET> struct result_of’
     result_of<f_f>::type a = 3;

Comment: It seems like that compiler want a type rather than a variable of that type

Comment: vector<int> vec; // is correct. but now I do this like: vector<int(0)> vec;

Comment: @LiuWeibo: You may use this that [way](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af1dc0b6c93a2a26).

Comment: @Jarod42 how to use these types as type identifier to define some variable?

Comment: `typeof` might help if your compiler supports it.

Comment: This will break if the function is overloaded

Comment: @PasserBy: If the function is overloaded, getting the result type might be ambiguous anyway ;-) (still possibility to cast to correct type, but then, we don't have to type the name of the function ;-) )

Comment: I'm looking into the possibility of grabbing the right overload if arguments are provided, not too optimistic though :P

Comment: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4533801/4832499), not going into that craziness.

Comment: @Jarod42 How can I define variable by typeof? This is mostly confusing part of all

Comment: @LiuWeibo: Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba4e116b01be3ac9)