# Is a float 4 bytes on all windows platforms

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am writing a program in c++, that stores different data in a binary file.  I am running into issues because the size of a data type can change from one system to another.  I was wondering if floats are always 4 byte on all windows platforms.  The only platform i am building this program for is windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not define the size of `float` -- your compiler defines that.

What Windows defines is a type named `FLOAT` in windef.h.  It's defined as `typedef float FLOAT;`.  That's the type name the Win32 API uses and the one you should be using if Windows support is important to you. I doubt any Windows compiler will ever change its format for `float` types, but Microsoft certainly could change their `typedef` for `FLOAT` and that would change what it means to support `float` on all versions of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Not guaranteed by the C++ standard, but most machines today follows ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559:2011, or the identical [IEEE-754 floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard. By this standard, the single precision `float` is 4 bytes.

You can check `std::numeric_limits< float >::is_iec559` in `<limits>` to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Of course, it may be wise to throw a `static_assert(sizeof(float)==4, "whatever")` in there (or a plain old non-static assert, if the former is not supported by your compiler), just to (a) document your assumption, and (b) notify you *if* by some cruel twist of fate your platform suddenly does not have 4-byte floats.

Comment: Data type formats aren't determined by the operating system; they're determined by compilers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that sooner or later *every* developer will stumble into a `#define float double /* more precision */` macro

Comment: @peppe perhaps, but that would be undefined behavior. :)

Comment: @CareyGregory: true, but the compiler (usually) doesn't make this decision in a vacuum. A sane compiler usually tries to stay compatible with the operating system's ABI, and the CPU's instruction set. It is certainly *possible* to create a compiler where a `float` has a different size, but on a CPU which works with 32-bit IEEE floating-point operands, and as long as you are not working on an OS which explicitly defines absurdly weird and contrived ABIs, it is a pretty safe assumption that your compiler will also use 4-byte `float`s

Comment: @jalf - substituting `double` for `float` is not undefined behavior.  It's just a hideously bad programming practice, which we will all stumble upon sooner or later.

Comment: @CareyGregory re-#defining language keywords *is* undefined behavior. It is nothing specific to `float` and `double`.

Comment: @jalf We'll have to agree to disagree since using `double` in every instance where `float` is used will result in precisely the behavior defined for `double`.  The only way you'd get undefined behavior would be if the usage of `float` were also undefined in that case.

Comment: @CareyGregory what a weird thing to say. Don't you care whether what you are saying is **correct**? The only thing that matters is what the C++ language specification says. What you or I "agree" with hardly matters to the compiler. So no, we will not have to agree to disagree. Not when we can find out what is actually correct.

Comment: @CareyGregory Now, after looking it up, the actual wording is a bit fluffy: as long as you do not include any standard library headers, you *may* be free to #define anything you like. But a TU which includes a std lib header yields undefined behavior if it defines a preprocessor macro with the same name as a keyword. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726204/c-preprocessor-define-ing-a-keyword-is-it-standards-conforming/2726221#2726221). So yes, it is undefined behavior in any non-trivial code (anything that includes std lib headers), and *maybe* undefined if in other cases as well.

Comment: That is what the C++ language specification has to say on the matter. Unless you can find somewhere in the standard which contradicts this, then "agreeing" or "disagreeing" is nonsensical.

Comment: No, I'm not going to argue with the spec.  So #defining keywords will produce undefined behavior in the std lib headers.  OK, fine, but my point was that doing something like `#define float double` within your own code essentially has the exact same effect as using an editor to refactor all your `float`s to `double`s, and we know that does not _in and of itself_ produce undefined behavior.

Comment: @CareyGregory no, I didn't say "in std lib headers", I said "in translation units which **include** a std lib header". So no, `#define float double` does not have the effect you would expect. *That is what undefined behavior means*. The standard guarantees that `#define` works as you'd expect *as long as* you stay away from overriding those particular names with macros. If you do that, it is **not** guaranteed to be equivalent to using your IDE to refactor. `#define X Y` does *not* mean "blindly replace X with Y", it means "replace X with Y in the cases specified by the standard".

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has 4 bytes only but it is not guaranteed. You may check the [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for reference.

You can check by cross platform behavior like this:-

```
#include <cassert>
int main () {
    assert(sizeof(float) == 4);
    // If control goes here you can be sure float is 4 bytes.

}
```