# Can I disable static asserts?

Tags: c++, static-assert

I have some rather costly `static_assert` calls scattered throughout my code. While these are valuable, they are often superfulous and significantly contribute to compile time and memory usage.

Can I disable them?

Comment: Yes. By removing them.

Comment: @Rapptz How would I re-enable them?

Comment: Are you sure these `static_assert` calls are responsible for all that overhead?

Comment: @Brian not all of it, but many of them include non-trivial meta-functions that contribute substantially and aren't needed for all builds.

Comment: The only way to disable `static_assert`s is by removing them from the code which will be compiled, for example by using the preprocessor. They do not in any way contribute to the compiled code.

Comment: On a somewhat 'meta' note. You should really start accepting answers. Your past 20 or so questions have no accepted answers. That's typically looked down upon here.

Comment: @Rapptz I tend to wait until I either receive a perfect answer or until I'm confident the answer is as good as what can be done given the question. I always mark answers eventually, with very few exceptions (take a look at my history). Do you think this is bad practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap them in the standard `NDEBUG` macro.

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
static_assert(...);
#endif
```

That way for release builds you can disable them just like regular `assert`. Although I don't really see a purpose to this.

If you don't like wrapping up the calls in a macro, you can define a macro that does it for you:

```
#ifndef STATIC_ASSERT
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(true, "")
#endif // NDEBUG
#endif // STATIC_ASSERT
```

Usage is similar to a regular `static_assert`. Note that if your program defines a keyword and includes a standard library header then it is [undefined behaviour to define a `static_assert` macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2726221/1381108).

Comment: I'm not particularly fond of this solution, but I guess it would do the job.

Comment: @quant Due to their compile-time aspect this is the only way to do it. Either that or removing them out right.

Comment: I really don't recommend coupling static checks (`static_assert`) with runtime-checks. If you want to remove one of them, it is quite possible you don't want to disable the others too.

Comment: @Deduplicator It could be replaced by whatever macro defined during the compilation process. I just used `NDEBUG` due to familiarity.

Comment: The replacement `do { } while(0)` won't work for `static_assert`s in namespace scope or in class bodies.

Comment: @reima Good catch. I can't think of a good way to fix that outside of moving the semicolon to the macro. Using a comment such as `/**/` will just lead a warning which is an error with -Werror.

Comment: How about `#define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(true, "")`?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can either wrap them, each for itself, in its own `#ifdef`:

   ```
   #ifndef NO_STATIC_ASSERT
   static_assert(...);
   #endif
   ```
2. Or, you can define your own `STATIC_ASSERT`:

   ```
   #ifndef NO_STATIC_ASSERT
       #define STATIC_ASSERT(...) /**/
   #else
     #define STATIC_ASSERT(...) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__)
   #endif
   ```

   - In practice, `#define static_assert(...)` works too, though it is UB.
3. Or, you can just manually remove them.

That way you can remove their influence on compilation-performance (they never had any influence on runtime-performance anyway).

Comment: neat, I didn't think of that second one. Thanks :)

Comment: defining your own `static_assert` macro is undefined behaviour

Comment: @Deduplicator Defining keywords through the preprocessor is undefined behaviour iif the TU or header includes a standard library header which is likely. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2726221/1381108).

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes. The comments by Johannes seems to support my claims and I trust him. This is a pretty old and long winded debate with a lot of history though.

Comment: @Deduplicator It's in the latest draft [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/source/lib-intro.tex#L2043). I don't want to prolong this discussion though. Discuss this in the [Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) if you want.

Comment: @Rapptz: No need. I looked for all the other cites, but that one is certainly enough.