# C++11 Redefine delete without affecting =delete

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using Visual C++ 2013.

I need to redefine my delete keyword (yet another memory management tool)

```
#define delete foo(SOME,PARA,METERS), delete
```

The purpose is to redirect delete to an overridden version of mine, but I have an issue when using the "= delete" keyword or using external code using it.

```
Class Something {
public:
    Something() {}
    Something(const Something &) = delete;
}
```

Note : VC13 gives the following errors :

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'instance'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

**Question**

Is there a way to redefine delete without affecting =delete ?

**Notes (edition)**

Redefining a keyword is indeed something to handle with care and could probably be avoided by another design in practically any case. I am already fully aware of that and I **do not ask for a workaround**. See this question more as a research than an actual production development.

This being said I just want to discuss here the issue that we have a keyword having two different meanings in two different situations.

So the question is simply about defining delete when used as a release operation and not as a "no implementation" mark.

Comment: `#define delete ...` sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Implement `operator delete` instead of using MACRO.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `operator delete()` instead. That seem to be more expected...

Comment: No, there isn't. This looks like a definite [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You will also need to watch out for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2726221/4342498

Comment: I do override delete, but I do need to redirect the standard delete to alternate overrides with different parameters, eventually context conditioned.
I could also just create a mydelete operator and use it along my code.
I could also use lots of workarounds, but I am mostly interested in knowing if there is anyway to define delete and not affecting =delete.

Comment: Never in your life you should even consider `#defin`ing a keyword. There is only one possible exception - when dealing with moronic libraries, I have seen a case or two when one had to redefine `private` to `public`. Wasn't something to be proud of, but a neccessary evil. But `#defin`ing `delete` or `new` is clearly insance.

Comment: By the way, not only you are breaking `= delete`. You will also break `operator delete`, and `delete[]`.

Comment: @SergeyA it looks like he want to replace operators with it. Problem, that he breaks ALL code which have written delete anywhere. Like standard library, which probably would not expect it.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, true - I am just showing Ben that the thing he asks about is not the only thing which will stop working.

Comment: If not used everyday and possibly threatening, redefining new and/or delete is not uncommon.
For instance `#define new new(__FILE__,__LINE__)` is very commonly seen.
Defining delete (moreover to remap it to a custom override) do not break if all cases are addressed. Here I can address mostly any. I still break the =delete function keyword.
But please, I understand that this is an uncommon case and that there are a lot of possible workarounds. But the question regards mostly the =delete functions and how to have them not affected by a redefinition of delete, even if it is a bad idea

Comment: `delete` is a keyword in C++. If you use a macro to change the meaning of a keyword you're deep in undefined-behavior land.

Answer (score 7):

> I need to redefine my delete keyword

No, you don't.

> The purpose is to redirect delete to an overridden version of mine,

You are allowed to provide your own definition of `operator delete`. This does not require redefining the keyword. As an added benefit, providing your own definition of `operator delete` also affects all library code which uses the `delete` keyword, even library code that has been compiled without including any of your headers, which seems like something you'd want.

Recommended further reading about that, including a simple example: [operator delete, operator delete[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)

Comment: I would rather end after the first sentence :). (No you don't).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Obviously the design I chose that led me to this issue could be worked around (in my case with a lot of pain, but this is not the point). But since one can define delete, one might it a case when it could be of any use.
Here this is the case and I found nothing for the moment discussing the conflict between defining delete and the =delete functions in C++11

Comment: @Ben, see my comment under your question: `= delete` is not the only thing which breaks.

Comment: `s/this issue could be worked around/this issue must be fixed/`

Comment: @SergeyA In fact you can avoid these issues.
For instance when redefining delete and having overridden operator delete[] before you can make a delete[] work with a `#define delete foo(), delete` for instance

Answer (score 3):

See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) for **replaceable deallocation functions**. You can override the global delete operators.