# If statement logic reverse

Tags: c++, if-statement, logic, logical-operators

```
bool x = someFuncThatReturnsTrueorFalse();
if (!x && (str1.length() != str2.length()) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    // do something
}
```

How would I rearrange the code above to eliminate the else statement?
I need to do nothing if bool = false and str1 and str2 have different lengths. Otherwise, I need to do something (e.g. function call).

For the life of me, I can't think of any way to change this. Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Trivial boolean algebra.    The opposite of `if (A && B)` is `if (!(A && B))`  which is equivalent to `if ((!A) || (!B))`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is putting `!()` around the condition.

```
bool x = someFuncThatReturnsTrueorFalse();
if (!(!x && (str1.length() != str2.length())) {
    // do something
}
```

Another way is using De Morgan's laws: `!(A && B)` is equivalent to `!A || !B`.

```
bool x = someFuncThatReturnsTrueorFalse();
if (x || (str1.length() == str2.length()) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `bool` is a keyword.

Comment: @cigien It may be defined as macro.

Comment: @cigien  [C++ preprocessor #define-ing a keyword. Is it standards conforming? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726204/c-preprocessor-define-ing-a-keyword-is-it-standards-conforming)

Comment: This is the right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52203750/8372853), as the comment points out :) Maybe not UB, but definitely not allowed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this was meant to be pseudo-code. I have just updated to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: @user3354230 Thank you for notifying. Updated answer according to that.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong leaving as is. The code will still compile