# About operator << overloading

Tags: c++

Here is a simple "hello world" program.

```
int main(){
  std::cout << "hello world\n";
  return 0;
}
```

How do I make the program print "hello world"+{some other string}
for example: "hello world this is my string"
without touching and changing the main ?.
I tried to overload the << operator of string  but it didn't work.
thank you.

Comment: *How* did you attempt to overload the `<<` operator?

Comment: Also, whay do you want to do that overloading to add extra information? If it's just plain curiosity then that's okay, but please state so. Otherwise please [edit] your question to ask about the *actual* problem you want to solve, telling us what you think might solve it. Always ask for the actual problem, to avoid your question being [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Do you want this overload only for `"hello world\n"` or any character literal string?

Answer (score 3):

You [*can*](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f45690f70c7281f) do this, but you really shouldn't.

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, const char (&)[13]) {
    return os << "hello world this is my string\n";
}

int main(){
  std::cout << "hello world\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for .. so thank you very much I just did not define the char* parameter as const... my bad

Comment: I didn't think this is allowed by the standard. If I'm wrong please let me know.

Comment: @Bathsheba it's not adding to `std`, so I don't know why it would be prohibited. Interestingly `const char *` in `::` is unambiguously worse than the one in `std`, and `const char (&)[N]` is ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

> How do I make the program print "hello world this is my string" without touching and changing the main ?

You are asking for sneaky tricks, I presume?  Macros are infamous for being sneaky.

```
int main(){
  std::cout << "hello world this is my string\n";
  return 0;
}
#define main not_main

// "the main", below, has not been touched.

int main(){
  std::cout << "hello world\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: technically the second is UB (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2726221/4117728), the first is fine I think

Comment: Favorite answer!

Comment: Love the first one. The behaviour of the second one is undefined. (I'll upvote if you remove it.)

Comment: @Bathsheba I've avoided macros so well, I don't know if I could `#define 0` to have the same horrific effect.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to do this in a defined manner. You've made it difficult due to the newline character which we somehow need to workaround. (We can't rely on a destructor for example). What we need to do is to make our own output stream class, and set it to be the one that `std::cout` uses:

1. Derive a class from `std::ostream`.
2. Implement `operator<<` for `const char*`. That needs to replace `\n` with the extra text you want, or something along those lines.
3. Imbue that stream into `std::cout` using `rdbuf`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf

Clearly all this fun can take place outside `main`. (3) needs some thought: you can use a constructor and instantiate a static instance of that class above `main`. That's an idiomatic way of running code before `main`.