# Variable name 'xor' results in internal compiler error 'segmentation fault'!

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-construction

Compiling this code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int xor = 0;
}
```

via

```
g++ main.cpp
```

results in:

```
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
```

with

```
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659).
```

Renaming the variable removes the error.

Question: Is gcc from Apple crap?

Comment: Seems like a candidate for a bug report to the gcc team.

Comment: For me on 4.4.1-4ubuntu9, it just gives a normal error, "expected unqualified-id before ‘^’ token." (xor is an alias for ^).  No segmentation fault.

Comment: Note that unless you installed gcc independently, it's a symlink to clang since OSX 10.9 (Mavericks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time your compiler segfaults, it's a bug. Your already reduced test case is a perfect candidate to be reported to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/).

Comment: It should be reported to Apple (http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/).  They can best determine if it's a bug they introduced, or present in upstream.  If it is in upstream, they will typically file a bug there.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I reported it to Apple as well as to the gcc team.

Answer (score 3):

and_eq, bitand, bitor, compl, not, not_eq, or, or_eq, xor and xor_eq are keywords which are enabled with -ansi or -foperator-names

you have one of those switches enabled?

check also out: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419805/when-did-and-become-an-operator-in-c)

Comment: @Wolfgang, it's not really g++-specific, or hidden.  The C++ standard says `xor` is reserved, and using a reserved word in another context is undefined behavior.  That means anything can happen.  Of course, it's preferable for the compiler to print a clear error message.

Comment: @Matthew I meant it as a joke. To use logical operators spelled out in conditions is quite a nice feature which makes code more readable (esp. to collegues who are used to scripting languages), but i doubt that many C++ programmers know about or use this.