# Should I use "&&" or "and"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, boolean-logic

I'm using C++11 and both are compiling without any warning, witch one is the best way to do it?

```
if(a && b)
```

or

```
if(a and b)
```

Comment: Then why everybody is blaming `and`?

Comment: Whichever one you prefer. This question will only serve to solicit opinions on style.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes A lot of *old* devs like my teachers

Comment: `&&` is the idiomatic way, for no good rational reason. That's just they way it's done most of the time.

Comment: Because they are used to `&&` and don't like to use what they don't know as it might expose a lack of knowledge on their part.

Comment: I'm curious - Is `and` a macro or a built in operator? Is this part of the C++11 standard? I've never seen the before...

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus11 it's a macro in `<iso646.h>` in C, but it's part of the language in C++, all versions.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus11 it is part of C++98. It just doesn't get used that much.

Comment: Cool. I never knew that! Praise C++.

Comment: It's still a macro in Microsoft's compiler. But that's a conformance issue on their part. They won't fix it because their internal codebase probably uses the keywords as identifiers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is anybody using the named boolean operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103313/is-anybody-using-the-named-boolean-operators)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> 2.6 Alternative tokens [lex.digraph]
>
> 1 Alternative token representations are provided for
>   some operators and punctuators.16
>
> 2 **In all respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the
>   same, respectively, as its primary token**, except for its spelling.17
>   The set of alternative tokens is defined in Table 2.

Can't paste table 2, but it explicitly states Alternative: `and`, Primary `&&` (same for `or` and `||`).

So they are absolutely identical.
If you want to try and convince yourself one is "better" than the other, that's your business. If someone else is trying to argue such, they'd better have a good reason.

Edit: The aforementioned Table 2:

```
Table 2 — Alternative tokens
Alternative Primary
<%          {
%>          }
<:          [
:>          ]
%:          #
%:%:        ##
and         &&
bitor       |
or          ||
xor         ˆ
compl       ~
bitand      &
and_eq      &=
or_eq       |=
xor_eq      ˆ=
not         !
not_eq      !=
```

Edit: Maybe worth noting, according to [Sebastian Redl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110294/should-i-use-or-and-logic/17110423#comment24755456_17110294), MS break the rules here.

Comment: So would that imply that it is legal, given `int x,y;`, to say `memcpy(bitand x, bitand y, sizeof x);`?

Comment: @supercat Legal, yes. You may even use `compl` to declare a destructor. But if I'm doing your code review, I may not be very polite about it!

Answer (score 8):

I prefer `&&` instead of `and`.

- `&&` is widely known and accepted, [while many don't even know that `and` is valid C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419805/when-did-and-become-an-operator-in-c).
- Some IDEs don't accept `and` (and friends) by default. For example [MSVC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555505/c-alternative-tokens).
- At least for me, the operator precedence of `&&` and `||` is ingrained into my head. While `and` and `or` have the same precedences as `&&` and `||`, the simple fact that I'm much less used to them makes it harder to read a condition.

On the other hand, `and` is more verbose and might be easier to use for programmers who have learned programming with languages that don't use `&&`. But one could argue that these people should learn C++ rather than try to change it's snytax.

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer 
    if(a and b)
, because there is always the chance to mix up accidently
    if(a && b)
with 
    if(a & b)
, causing you a lot of trouble..

Comment: Hmm... I wonder about consistency with `operator&&` ?  There is no operator overload for `operatorand`.  (I wonder how that would interact with the tokenizer if you tried to `operator and`?)

Comment: For the operator && there isn't an overload either, is it?

Comment: Yep, there is.  You can overload `&&` for your own classes.  The extra gotcha with that particular overload is that it disables short-circuit evaluation for `&&` (and similarly `||`) when used with your class (it becomes a normal function invocation, both parameters need to be evaluated before calling the function).

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that the difference between `bitand` and `and` is more obvious than `&&` and `&`. I'm sure this has bitten plenty of people in the past (though I can't think of an example in my code).

Comment: Tried the `operator and` with clang, and it is a tokenizer thing.  If you do `operatorand`, the tokenizer sees it as one token and uses it as a new function name.  If you do `operator and`, it sees them as two separate tokens and treats it the same as `operator &&` (and will even complain of a duplicate declaration if you try to declare both).

Answer (score 4):

As someone who programs in both C and C++, unless there's a good reason to use different alternatives in each language, I prefer to keep it consistent. Although `and` has been a part of the C standard for close to two decades, it requires a header file instead of being built into the language. Especially when a piece of code may be used in multiple projects, the hassle is just not worth it.

I've never seen a situation where  using `and` over `&&` would be advantageous. I can't imagine a modern development system without a <kbd>&</kbd> key, though maybe if you're trying to do something on an unusual platform (like directly programming on a severely limited mobile/embedded system) it would be useful. I also think it reduces the readability of my code for people who are very used to seeing `&&` as the logical and operator.