# What kind of operator are "not", "and" and "or" in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, user-defined

'Cause whenever I try one of these lines:

```
#define and &&
#define or ||
#define not !
```

I get the error:

```
1:9: error: "not"/"and"/"or" cannot be used as a macro name as it is an operator in C++
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419805/when-did-and-become-an-operator-in-c

Comment: Why... would you ever want to define those? Why make your code unreadable?

Comment: Unreadable? Come on.

Comment: Unexpected is unreadable. I bet next you'll be doing `#define loop for`

Comment: Nah. `#define for for(` is enough for me

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Apparently you're missing the point here: `and`  **already** means `&&`.

Comment: @MSalters: They do but that's no reason to use them. Alternate operators for the same thing AFAIK is a hack to account for obsolete character encodings. Trigraphs are already slated for removal in C++17 and I wouldn't be surprised if the rest of the silly alternate representations will follow shortly after.

Comment: I guess starting coding with strange, non-natural symbols makes you less flexible in reading code, as I can read C/C++ syntax without problems even if I started with and, or, not, end, then, where you seem to have problems when encountering non-symbolic keywords.

Answer (score 1):

These keywords are already defined. Please have a look http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative